# How to split a numpy array into several lists using one or more of the same delimiter

Tags: python, numpy

Assuming I have the following numpy array (or list):

```
a = [0,0,1,2,4,1,0,1,2,0,0,0,1,3,0]
```

How can I split this into a list of separate lists, using the occurence of one or more zeros as the delimiter? The answer should be as follows:

```
ans = [ [1,2,4,1], [1,2], [1,3] ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `itertools.groupby`

```py
from itertools import groupby
a = [0,0,1,2,4,1,0,1,2,0,0,0,1,3,0]
[list(g) for k,g in groupby(a, key=lambda x: x!=0) if k!=0]
```

```
[[1, 2, 4, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the performance:

```
ans = list(filter(None, ''.join(map(str, a)).split('0')))
ans = list(map(lambda x: list(map(int, x)), ans))
```